# getting count and group by in PSQL using Case Or RoundOff and pivot based on a point? how many pupils have passed and how many have failed

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

A pupil can pass or fail in test.
Total Marks = 100.
0-30 marks means fail.
31-100 marks means passed exam.

Example:
I have table called pupil:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE pupil
    (id integer primary key,
     marks integer,
     maxmarks integer)
```

Now insert some values like

```sql
insert into pupil (id, marks, maxmarks) values (1,11,100),(2,21,100),(3, 60,100);
```

Now the table looks like this:

```
id | marks | maxmarks 
----+-------+----------
  1 |    11 |      100
  2 |    21 |      100
  3 |    60 |      100
```

I want to see how many have got between 0-30 and how many have got between 31-100 marks

So I try to think of using group by and then getting count.

I wrote this query:

```sql
    select marks, count(*) from pupil group by marks;
```

which returns me this result:

```
 marks | count 
-------+-------
    60 |     1
    11 |     1
    21 |     1
```

But I don't want that result, I am expecting this result.

```
 marks | count 
-------+-------
 0-30  |     2
30-100 |     1
```

0-30 can be just 0 or 30 also, I don't care, I am interested in count column mostly.
I tried various group by and case clauses and also heard about something called "pivot", but I am not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple approach would be using a conditional `GROUP BY`:

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cd874b9641e2837d1a969a16c487c57d)

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN marks <= 30 THEN 
        '0-30'
        ELSE '31-100'
    END,
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    pupil
GROUP BY (marks <= 30)
```

Alternative approach could be the usage of a `UNION` clause:

```
SELECT
    '0-30',
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    pupil
WHERE marks <= 30

UNION

SELECT
    '31-100',
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    pupil
WHERE marks > 30
```

Comment: Thanks for coming up with the answer. I did EXPLAIN on your queries. Group with a simple case is better because cost is 45 and for Union the cost is 75. Both are low but yeah!